# Include jQuery into C#

Tags: c#, jquery, web-parts

How to include jQuery library (.js) into webpart on С#? I need to write script, which using jQuery, and use it for action on click.

p.s.: Webpart is not visual

p.s.: is it real? =)

Comment: How do you want the user to click something in your web part that is not visual? First hit with google: [Creating a Web Part with Client-side Script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd584169(v=office.11).aspx)

Comment: W.R.T. Webparts, "Visual" means you get a designer (.ascx and .ascx.cs) in Visual Studio - not that it doesn't render anything without being Visual :)

Comment: This question isn't making much sense. If my telepathy is plugged in right why now check to see if $ is defined - if not output a link to a CDN JQ? You're doing it all wrong though - either way. Webparts are the spawn of the devil.. and not in a good way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you need to include a line like

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(
    "JQueryInclude",
    "/path/to/your/jquery.js");
```

somewhere in your webpart's code where it will be called on every page load, e.g. in the `OnLoad` method:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(
        "JQueryInclude",
        "/path/to/your/jquery.js");
    base.OnLoad(e);
}
```

This will cause a line like

```
<script src="/path/to/your/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to appear in your page source, and you can then use JQuery in your webpart.